# Debian install failing due to CDROM not being detected

Tags: debian, debian-installer

A similar question got asked but got closed.

If you install Debian 7.7 to a USB in Windows with unetbootin and then try to install Debian from that USB, it will complain that it 'cannot mount CDROM' and the install will not go any further.

Comment: Just unplug the USB stick and then plug it again.  Now try to detect CD-ROM again.  It works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way around this problem is to rename the Debian .iso file to a .img file, and then to write the image to the USB with Win32DiskImager (I used 0.9.5 and it worked fine). The install will then work.

Answer (score 9):

You can mount manually in a shell window (Ctrl + Fnumber)

`mount -t vfat /dev/sdb /cdrom`

But, the option of warsong works fine. It seems like a UNetBootin-Win bug u_u

Comment: if you are using installer over ssh (putty or similar) you need to use <Ctrl> + A then choose 1-4 to select shell (`screen` commands)

Answer (score 8):

I got the same error message when booting from a second partition of my usb stick. [Zorbax' solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/170131/245294) helps here too, however you need to choose the correct partition. For my case it was

```
mount -t vfat /dev/sdb2 /cdrom
```

Comment: I had to use the command without the parameter -t, `mount /dev/sdb1 /cdrom`

Comment: I had to use mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /cdrom

Answer (score 2):

Acccording to [Debian-faq](https://www.debian.org/CD/faq/#record-windows)

> This might be a little problem on older versions of Windows, as many Windows image-burning programs use their own formats for CD images.

And [Wiki-ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager/iso2usb)

> Win32DiskImager is particularly good for pre-release testing and new releases, when the standard tools like Unetbootin might not be ready

Maybe there are an issue with *unetbootin* on some windows distro . You can use an alternative like : *win32diskimager* or [Refus](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)  recommaded by Ubuntu , or *ImgBurn* ...

Answer (score 2):

In order to install Debian 9.5.0 on the bare metal, I had to enable IOMMU on my motherboard BIOS (for the keyboard and mouse to work). After that, I put Debian DVD 1 ISO into my pendrive with Rufus tool using "dd" mode. To make the graphical installer read the packages from my pendrive as if it were a CD-ROM, I had to plug the pendrive into a USB 2.0 port available at my machine's front panel. And to finish up installation, I said "no" to "force UEFI" option.

(I haven't experienced bare metal install issues with Windows over USB 3, though)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

For QEMU (if a switch like "-cdrom installer.iso" is used):

```
mount /dev/vdb2 /cdrom
```