# Debian - Install required CD ROM

Tags: debian, system-installation, debian-installer

Today I was trying to install Debian Jessie (8.6 20160917 15:03), using netinstall ISO, Live CD ISO (on usb device) and network boot install.

But every time, after create all partitions the installer ask for a cd rom on /media/cdrom and get stuck there.

Any hint on this problem? I don't know wath to do.

EDIT:

Using a live cd install, I follow this steps:

- Click on Application Launcher
- Execute "Install Debian Jessie"
- Select a Language: English
- Select your location: Other - South America - Chile
- Configure Locales: United States - en_US.UTF-8
- Configure the keymap: Latin America
- Detect network hardware - Load firmware for Realtek device - No (I tried with the realtek firmware on an USB device but it not detect it)
- Configure the network: eth0 (same result with wlan0)
- Set the machine and domain name
- Set root password
- Set user and password
- Configure the clock: Santiago
- Partition Schema:

  - sda5 ext2 /boot
  - sda6 LVM

    - ext4 /home
    - ext4 swap
    - ext4 /

At this point I got this message:

/media/cdrom/: Please insert the disc labeled 'Debian GNU/Linux 8 *Jessie* - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20160917-15:03' in the drive '/media/cdrom' and press enter.

**UPDATE**
I just skip the internet connection settings and install the defaults "CD-ROM" packages. Then update the sources.list file with some jessie repositories and did an update

`sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: The installation will ask you if you want to add any mirrors. Say no and it will continue only with the so called base system.

Comment: Which did you use to install? The Netinstall ISO or the Live CD ISO? Or are you saying you tried three methods and got the same error?

Comment: @roaima Yes, I tried three diferents methods and got the same error. I will edit including all steps using a LIVE CD Instalation (on a USB device)

Comment: May be relevant to some people: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170069/debian-install-failing-due-to-cdrom-not-being-detected - tl;dr, you can go to shell and mount the USB device partition again under /cdrom and it then finds it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume it is asking for a different CD/DVD to the single one you've got for the installation.

This is because it cannot find the packages you've requested on the CD/DVD and it needs to get them online. But presumably you haven't provided a mirror either so it's got no recourse except to assume it's an offline installation and you have a collection of CDs/DVDs ready to feed it.

Solution: either provide a mirror or don't ask for packages that aren't on the single installation disk.

If you're running from the NetInstall ISO, then there's only enough for a minimal system on the image. Everything else has to come from the network (hence the name).

Comment: I did a mirror selection. This is no the first time that I install debian, but today I downloaded the latest Debian Image. So, on netinstall Debian will download everything from internet (I assume)

Answer (score 1):

You can mount your removable media manually as describe here:

[D.3.4.2. Mount Partitions](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/apds03.html.en)

> Current Debian systems have mountpoints for removable media under /media, but keep compatibility symlinks in /. Create these as as needed, for example:

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> then type:

```
 cd /media
 mkdir cdrom0
 ln -s cdrom0 cdrom
 cd /
ln -s media/cdrom
```

Then press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Just unplug your usb, wait a few moments, plug it back into the same port and the install should continue after pressing 'next'.

Comment: Wow, this actually worked for me 5 years later. Trying to install the latest Debian that I burned to a flash drive via BalenaEtcher and the installer couldn't locate all the drivers and asked for CD-ROM. After reading your answer I unplugged the flash drive, waited a few seconds, plugged it back in, then selected "YES" to locate the drivers on CD-ROM (again) and it found them.